# Continuous map in specific topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let 
$$X=\{1, 2, 3\} \qquad \mathcal{T}_X = \{\emptyset, X,\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$$
and
$$Y=\{a, b, c\} \qquad \mathcal{T}_Y = \{\emptyset,Y,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$$
be topological spaces. We define the map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ via
$$f(1)=a \quad f(2)=b \quad f(3)=b.$$

This map is continuous, because the preimage of every open set in $Y$ is open in $X$, i.e. $f^{-1}(\{a\})=\{1\}$,  $f^{-1}(\{b\})=\{2,3\}$ are open in $X$.

Is my understanding correct here? Thanks.

Comment: yes you are correct, the preimage of $\lbrace a,b \rbrace$ is open as it is $f ^{-1}(a) \cup f ^{-1}(b)$ which are both open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you are correct. But to prove continuity, you need to show that the preimage of *every* open set in $Y$ is open in $X$. This means that you also need that $f^{-1}(\emptyset)$, $f^{-1}(Y)$ and $f^{-1}(\{a, b\})$ are open. The first two sets are trivially open and $f^{-1}(\{a, b\}) = X$ is also an open set.